# Browser does not show .JPG files (with capital letters)

Tags: php, html

In my site, I give an option to upload images with .jpg and .JPG extension. They both work and I can see both on the server itself.

When I try to see in the browser the photos with the .jpg extension by calling them name.jpg, they work. When I call to the othername.JPG (which is called that way on the server) it does not work and does not show it. othername.jpg does not work too.

Comment: On unix, filenames are case sensitive. Did you download both via FTP and checked them in an image viewer? What are the http headers for each image? 404 or 500?

Comment: It shows nothing. When checking in FireBug, it shows the src and writes that it can not load the url.

Comment: I've downloaded it using an FTP client and it shows it fine in an image viewer. What do you mean by http headers?

Comment: @Vadiklk - Are you sure you get *nothing*? It's really weird that neither your web server nor your browser display an error message if the picture is invalid or cannot be found :-?

Comment: What happens when you access the image directly from the browser like `http://mywebsite.com/images/othername.JPG`?

Comment: Please provide one URL of a working image and one of a non-working (but existing) image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose your web server is not configured to send the `Content-Type: image/jpeg` HTTP header for such files. It's possible that some browsers refuse to display them as pictures if the MIME type does not match. If you happen to be using Apache, you can fix it yourself in an `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType image/jpeg .JPG
```

You should also consider that you cannot count of URLs being case-insensitive: FOO can equal foo... or not. Use always the exact case and save yourself future problems.

**Edit:**

Before misconfiguring random stuff, you can follow this checklist and see what fails exactly:

1. Is the URL valid? `Foo.jpg` is not the same as `foo.jpg`.
2. Does the browser receive the file? Firebug should tell you.
3. What's the HTTP response code? Firebug should tell you.
4. What's the `Content-Type` header? Firebug should tell you.

Common status codes:

- `404`: the file could not be found. Most likely, your URL is wrong.
- `403`: you are not authorised to see the file. It can be a permissions issue.
- `500`: generic server error code. You should open your hosting service control panel and have a look at the error log.

Comment: I am using the hostgator service, and not my localhost server. Where do I add that there? And what about .PNG? And shouldn't it know to recognize the .JPG as jpeg when I upload it with the imagejpeg method on php?

Comment: I am using HostGator too as my hosting and never encountered such error, maybe as I said is from your upload file or some ``htaccess``

Comment: @Vadiklk, I can see you slightly lost so I've updated my question with some things you can check. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your using linux/apache right? make the filenames lowercase. its the default for them to be accessed on linux.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the contents of that file, maybe your script is messing up JPG uploaded files.
if that doesn't work maybe it's from your system .. an `.htaccess`

Look in error logs for anything that is related to this file.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can't seem to find any problem, and I don't remembering having those problems before (using HG for a lot of time now)

Comment: if you are not posting the upload process or htaccess ... I cannot predict how your system works. I'm telling you I use HG over 3 years and never has a problem from HG's systems .. all errors from my side